# Call post to vue with laravel error 419 csrf-token

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, csrf

I´m working in a project with Laravel and I implement Vue to make asynchronous task.
My problem is that Laravel use in post methos csrf token protection and I don´t how to pass this token to the javascript call. How can I do it ?

```
<header id="heading" >
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <h1 class="text-center">Preparación de Pedidos</h1>
        @if( $mensaje != '' )
        <div class="alert alert-success">{{ $mensaje }}</div>
        @endif
</header>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    const app = new Vue({
        el: '#vue', 
        data: {
            mensaje: '',
            pedidos: [],
            csrf: document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content'),
        },
        created() {
            $.post('/prestashop/intranet2/almacen/get_tipos_pedidos_preparacion', {}).then(function(response) {
                this.tipos = response.body.tipos;
            }, function(response) {
                alert('error');
                console.log(response);
            });
            this.updateEstadisticas();
        },
    });
 </script>
```

In debug I can see the token

```
_token:"kUM5V4gwOweyE09jdoVP3lvta1DHyYpTlrGnSfx9"
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `_token` instead of `csrf`.

```
 data: {
            mensaje: '',
            pedidos: [],
             "_token": document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content'),
        },
```

Also instead of getting token from a query selector you can achive it like this too.

```
 data: {
     "_token":{{ csrf_token() }}
    },
```

Comment: data gets correctly the token but the error 419 appear.

Comment: is token also getting

Comment: could you please refresh the page and try. if error still exist can we have a screen shot please

Comment: I refresh the page with 'Ctrl+F5' but nothing changes

Answer (score 1):

If you use VueJS.
Route Laravel, you should put it in api.php instead of web.php

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the problem comes by other part of code, so CSRF isn´t the problem.